# How to automate loading a ".txt" file from local to MFC application using pywinauto?

Tags: mfc, ui-automation, pywinauto

I'm trying to load a "**.txt**" file from local to MFC application using **pywinauto** or at-least I need to able to type the text in the "File name:" section and then able to click Open button (as shown in the below screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

Following is the code which i'm using:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time
app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"path of the application (.exe)" ')
window = app.Dialog
window.Wait('ready')
button = window.Button
button.Click()
app.Open.edit.SetText("Test_File%r.txt" % b)
app.Open.Open.Click()
```

I searched many blogs for this and couldn't find the solution. Any help is appreciated!!!
Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to find wrapper object for the whole File Open dialog?

Comment: No, I couldn't able to find that.
You can take example of "Save as" command in notepad application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made progress on this and it worked for me.

Below is the code which i'm using now:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time
import ctypes
app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"path of the application (.exe)" ')
window = app.Dialog
window.Wait('ready')
button = window.Button
button.Click()
button2 = window.Button10
button2.Click()
app.Open.edit.SetText("Hello.txt")
time.sleep(2)
app.Open.Open.click_input()
```

Comment: Camel case methods like `SetText` are deprecated (will be removed this year), use `set_text` which is recommended by PEP8.

Comment: Save As example from pywinauto repo: [examples/save_from_firefox.py](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/save_from_firefox.py)

Comment: Got it. Thank you.